# No module named urllib3

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, urllib3

I wrote a script to call an API and ran it successfully last week. This week, it won't run. I get back the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "user_audit.py", line 2, in <module>
    import requests
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    import urllib3
ImportError: No module named urllib3
```

I've confirmed that packages is up to date, tried uninstalling and reinstalling it, but nothing has worked so far. Can someone help?

**ADDENDUM**

I installed urllib3 as suggested by @MSHossain, but then got another error message. The new message referenced another file that I'd written, which had created a Python compiled file. The other file was using smptlib to attempt to send an email. I don't understand how this would happen, but I deleted the other file and my script ran without any problems. I've accepted the answer below as I was able to pip install urllib3, but it should have already been included in the requests module.

Comment: The actual code making the call would be really helpful.

Comment: firstly, make sure are you using it with correct python version?

Comment: @ChristianKönig It's failing on line 2, import requests. The other line references in the error message are to the request module itself.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Either urllib3 is not imported or not installed.

To import, use

```
import urllib3
```

at the top of the file. To install write:

```
pip install urllib3
```

into terminal.

It could be that you did not activate the environment variable correctly.
To activate the environment variable, write

```
source env/bin/activate
```

into terminal. Here `env` is the environment variable name.

Comment: Okay, installing urllib3 has fixed the issue. Very strange, as it is also part of requests module.

Comment: set your environment ... writing source env/bin/activate

Comment: $ pip install urllib3 \n
-bash: pip: command not found

Answer (score 6):

I already had it installed. Solved it by running `pip install --upgrade urllib3`

Hope it helps someone :)

Answer (score 5):

```
pip install urllib3
```

The reason it broke is that I had installed an incompatible version of `urllib3` as a transient dependency of `awscli`. You'll see such conflicts when you rerun the install.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by running

```
pip install --upgrade requests
```

Answer (score 2):

set you environment  by writing **source env/bin/activate** if **env** not found write **virtualenv env** first then **source env/bin/activate** , then check **pip freeze** if urllib3 not found there then reinstall urllib3, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Few minutes back, I faced the same issue. And this was because, I used virtual environment. I believe that due to venv directory, the pip installed might have stopped working.

Fortunately, I have setup downloaded in my directory. I ran the setup and chose the option to repair, and now, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me in PyCharm I had to put `import urllib3` at the top of the file as mentioned earlier then PyCharm gave the option to import. Even after installing it with  `pip`

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling urllib3 solves my problem. Run:

```
pip uninstall urllib3
pip install urllib3
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completness. It means the python installation you are using does not have the package installed, **be sure you are using the same python installation as the one where you are installing the package**.

For me what was happening is that I had a virtual environment made with **pyenv**, even when the virtual environment had the package installed and in its latest version, it was not found because somehow the underlaying python install was used and not the one where I had the urllib3 installed.

Solution: **Use the absolute path to the python binary**:

```
/home/[username]/.pyenv/versions/[envname]/bin/python python-script.py
```