# Sending sms Using Twilio on Python

Tags: python, twilio, importerror, urllib3

I typed in the provided sample code and obviously replaced my own info for the necessary spots:

```
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = "ACf2a49cff3675efb3344c603ef08748ef"
auth_token = "myauthtoken"
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(
    to="+mynumber", 
    from_="+twilionumber", 
    body="Hi its Gitty!")

print(message.sid)
```

And I received this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/Send a Text.py", line 1, in <module>
    from twilio.rest import Client
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twilio-6.5.0-
py2.7.egg\twilio\rest\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from twilio.http.http_client import TwilioHttpClient
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twilio-6.5.0-
py2.7.egg\twilio\http\http_client.py", line 1, in <module>
    from requests import Request, Session
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.18.3-
py2.7.egg\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
ImportError: No module named urllib3
```

I read somewhere else that I may need to re-install urllib3 or upgrade it, both of which I've done, and still no change to my error message. Help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["ImportError: No module named" when trying to run Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514593/importerror-no-module-named-when-trying-to-run-python-script)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No module named urllib3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42651145/no-module-named-urllib3)